# How to compare and print the output of three exe files with the same input?

Tags: c, printf, popen

I have  3 executable files MyExe1, MyExe2 and MyExe3  that I can run on the terminal (of my MacOs) as

```
$ ./MyExe1 9
9 is odd
$ ./MyExe2 9
9 is odd
$ ./MyExe3 9
9 is odd
$ ./MyExe1 8
8 is even
```

The inputs I have in my file `MyInputs.txt` (which contains the numbers 0, 1, ... 100).

How could I get the output printed ONLY for all the numbers where the outputs (for the same input) are different?

MyExe1, MyExe2 and MyExe3 accept only a single input (indeed a number), not a file, not a vector of numbers.

I found that there are several ways.. one is using popen(), execl(), system(). It would be possible to invoke MyExe1, MyExe2 and MyExe3 with popen()?

Comment: if MyExe# are outputting to STDOUT, popen() would be an easy option. Does it have to be done in C? Running on a list and comparing the outputs would be easier to do in a shell script.

Comment: Thank you! The output go to the screen so I would try popen(). Yes, in C. JJV.

Answer (score 0):

In a shell script on a Mac, you could write (`test-exe.sh`):

```
out1="MyExe1.output"
out2="MyExe2.output"
out3="MyExe3.output"
for file in "$out1" "$out2" "$out3"; do cp /dev/null "$file"; done
while read number
do
    ./MyExe1 "$number" >> "$out1"
    ./MyExe2 "$number" >> "$out2"
    ./MyExe3 "$number" >> "$out3"
done
diff3 "$out1" "$out2" "$out3"
```

Then you can read the numbers from `MyInputs.txt` by running:

```
$ sh test-exe.sh < MyInputs.txt
…maybe some output…
$
```

If the outputs are all the same, there will be no output.  If there's a difference somewhere, the `diff3` program will report it.

---

> I have the impression that `diff3 "$out1" "$out2" "$out3"` requires the complete calculation of MyExe# (with all the input numbers from 1 to 100). Is not possible to avoid it? (If I need to deal with more numbers (vg. from 1 to 10 00000) I am afraid I will run [into] memory troubles.

There are various comments to make.  First, `diff3` works on the three files it is given. It doesn't much care how big they are.  You could run it on the output from each individual run of the executables.

Second, the outputs shown are quite small (say less than 30 bytes per run) — so one million outputs for each program doesn't generate 30 MiB of data, or 100 MiB in total.  There's nothing to stop you from running the script for 10,000 lines at a time and running `diff3` on each intermediate file.

For my money, I'd revise the programs so that they can read from standard input and do their calculations repeatedly.  If there are command-line arguments, process them as now (except allow more than one argument per invocation).  If there are no arguments, read lines from standard input and process the value on each line.  Again, this means the code potentially processes multiple inputs per invocation.

You can then divvy the input file up into chunks of a convenient size and run the three executables and compare the three results.  To borrow Perl's motto: TMTOWTDI — There's more than one way to do it.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Leffer.. Only a question. I have the impression that diff3 "$out1" "$out2" "$out3" requires  the complete calculation of MyExe# (with all the input numbers from 1 to 100). Is not possible to avoid it? (If I need to deal with more numbers (vg. from 1 to 10 00000) I am afraid I will run in memory troubles. Kindest regards, JJV.

Comment: I've added an addendum to my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Jonathan Leffler. Thank you very much for all the explanations. I really appreciate them. Kindest regards, JVV